# How to use a common method that is shared

Tags: java, methods

I have one project file in Netbeans

The following .java tabs are present in the project

grad.java
site.java

Now within each .java tab there is a method called

```
public void saveSingleTableAsExcel() throws FileNotFoundException{
.........
}
```

This method is identical in both .java files and it seems inefficient to have this identical method in both places.

How do i go about putting this method in one place which can then be shared by both .java tabs? Do i need to create a new java class with that one method in it, and then refer to that?

Apologies if this seems trivial but i have only been java coding for approx 1 year.

Comment: "_Do i need to create a new java class with that one method in it, and then refer to that?_". Yes, What are you waiting for?

Comment: Delete one of the methods. Create an object of the other class. Call the method on that new object. Done.

Comment: @ takendarkk can i just confirm you mean that i should create a new class and put the method in that?

Comment: I think you should start thinking in terms of classes and objects, not in terms of tabs in an editor or java files. In the world of the Java Virtual Machine, the entities that exist are not tabs or files. The tabs and files are just ways to organize source code.

Comment: @  RealSkeptic yep thats the hardbit to get round when learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider creating a [superclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)  for your classes - this is good if the two classes actually have a close conceptual and behavioural relationship.

If the two classes just have the same functionality but don't have any other relationship, you can consider creating / referring to a seperate class containing utility methods which are used a lot - like basic string operations, reading files, etc. Generally there are great libraries for those purposes.